# How to configure postCSS location for font file / url proccess?

Tags: node.js, font-face, postcss, parceljs

I am using Parcel to pack SCSS into using postCSS.
My postCSS config has only autoprefixer and tailwind.

My scss file has this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: NBE;
    src: url('../fonts/NBE-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/NBE-Regular.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/NBE-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/NBE-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

but it outputs

```
@font-face {
  font-family: NBE;
  src: url("/NBE-Regular.f90b15ca.eot");
  src: url("/NBE-Regular.f90b15ca.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("/NBE-Regular.6b2ab3ea.woff2") format("woff2"),
url("/NBE-Regular.2ec20d61.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Note the location under url(), so get a 404 for the font file.

I don't know what this hash or version thing is
And why does it change the URL like that?

UPDATE:
I noticed that all those files are copied to dist folder, however that folder is not the root, so URL is still wrong..

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question and you've likely solved it, I faced a similar situation and resolved it as follows. Perhaps it helps others.

*Note: the following are not settings for postCSS but for Parcel v2.*

#### Prevent Parcel from processing certain linked files

The [parcel-resolver-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-resolver-ignore) plugin allows you to specify patterns of files or file paths to ignore when processing. You can target specific files but also files referenced *in* other files, which makes it possible to skip processing of certain file patterns in your sass / css files. This prevents the copying of the linked files and accompanying rewriting of the url.

1. Install the plugin and create a `.parcelrc` config file (or extend your existing one) as described in the [package readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-resolver-ignore?activeTab=readme).
2. Then add a `parcelIgnore` block to your `package.json` file similar to the following.

```json
"parcelIgnore": [
    "img/.+",
    "fonts/.+"
],
```

Any files in the /fonts and /img folders that are referenced in your sass/css files are skipped. Your build script does not throw a "not found" error, the files are not copied to the dist folder and the url remains as you originally specified it in your sass file.

#### Copying static assets without processing

If you need to copy over your static assets to your dist folder, you can use the [parcel-reporter-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-reporter-static-files-copy) plugin, which allows you to specify a source folder of static files (in subfolders as desired) that are copied without any processing to your dist folder.

1. Install the plugin and create a `.parcelrc` config file (or extend your existing one) as described in the [package readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-reporter-static-files-copy?activeTab=readme).
2. Create a `static` directory in your source folder and place your assets in there. If you want to use your own folder names, add a `staticFiles` block to your `package.json` file similar to the following, specifying the folder to copy and optionally a subdirectory of your dist folder to copy them to.

```json
"staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": "./src/public",
    "staticOutPath": "assets"
}
```

Your build process will now copy across all static assets unchanged to your dist folder.